# "An unexpected error has occurred within this region of the page" when check code file on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

When I locate our project on Azure Devops, it cannot display code content as this error occurs when I open any C# file:

> An unexpected error has occurred within this region of the page.
> You can try reloading this component or refreshing the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a browser compatibility issue. The UI of the devops page is not compatible with some versions of the browser.

As a workaround, you can try to use chrome browser, or the latest edge browser. I use chrome to test without problems.